# TextArea with 10 lines and 35 characters per line

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with many elements. The page is scrollable, that means the page has a scrollbar in it. Down to the page I have a HTML textarea with a specified rows and columns attribute. 
Now I want a simple JavaScript solution which will help me to validate the the following points each time user enters any character:

1. The number of lines in the textarea is not greater than 10
2. Each line has less than or equal to 35 characters
3. If user crosses 35 character limit for any particular line then the 36th character will be automatically start from next line only if the total line numbers does not exceed 10, else it will show an error popup message and stops there.
4. User should be able to modify any lines(it may be last line or any middle lines) and still should follow all the above 3 points.

Comment: Have you tried to do this and failed? Post the errors and we'll gladly help.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to limit the amount of characters allowed in my textarea.
This not only counts the amount of characters it trims it if it gets to the end and it also writes out how many characters you have left.

I think all you need to do now is figure out how to add a new line (try something like text += "\r\n";) <- Not 100% sure on this peice.

```
        function textCounter(txtfield, cntFld, maxlimit){
         var field = document.getElementById(txtfield);
         var countfield = document.getElementById(cntFld);

                if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
                {
                        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
                }else { // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
                        countfield.innerHTML = maxlimit - field.value.length;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar case :

> MaxLenght of textarea = 1875 ;
>   MaxLenght of row      = 75 ;
>   Disable Enter, because over 75's multiple, SW automatically wrap text ;

This is it, with onkeydown trigger:

```
function wrapTextArea(event,id,maxLineLenght){

    // delete and canc
    if((recuperaKeyCode(event)!=8) && (recuperaKeyCode(event)!=46))  {

        var field =  document.getElementById(id).value;
        var nextIndex = 0;
        for(var i=0; field.length>nextIndex; i++){
            nextIndex=maxLineLenght*(i+1)+i;
            if(field.length==nextIndex){
                if(field.charAt(nextIndex)!= "\n"){
                    field=field.substring(0, nextIndex)+"\n"+field.substring(nextIndex, field.lenght);
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(id).value = field;
    } 
}
```

This is how I disabled enter key, where key = 13 :

```
function disableKey(event,key){

    if(recuperaKeyCode(event)==key){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```